# openssl error: adding extensions in section default

Tags: openvpn, openssl, ssl

I'm trying to make server stuff(cert, req, key) with easy-rsa tool:

```
./easyrsa build-server-full srv_name nopass
```

> Using configuration from ./openssl-1.0.cnf
>
> Enter pass phrase for
>   /var/services/homes/admin/easyrsa3/pki/private/ca.key:
>
> Check that the request matches the signature Signature ok
>
> The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows commonName
>   :ASN.1 12:'srv_name'
>
> ERROR: adding extensions in section default
>   1073879248:error:22097082:X509 V3 routines:DO_EXT_NCONF:unknown
>   extension name:v3_conf.c:125:
>
> 1073879248:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in
>   extension:v3_conf.c:95:name=copy_extensions, value=copy

Actually, easy_rsa under the hood is trying:

```
openssl ca -utf8 -in /var/services/homes/admin/easyrsa3/pki/reqs/srv_name.req -out /var/services/homes/admin/easyrsa3/pki/issued/srv_name.crt.Cdgy3Ao8QP -config ./openssl-1.0.cnf -extfile /var/services/homes/admin/easyrsa3/pki/extensions.temp -days 3650 -batch
```

What's wrong with copy_extensions? My openssl just doesn't have it?

Comment: We cant help if you don't provide the cnf file

Comment: @HostFission, The default one from easy-rsa3(https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/master/easyrsa3/openssl-1.0.cnf)